# Need to replace a string C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace:

```
string input = "%someAlphabets%.ZIP"
string replaceWith = "Hello"
string result = "Hello.ZIP"
```

I tried with `Regex.Replace(inputString,"[%][A-Za-z][%]", replacedWith);` but it is not working.

Comment: String.Format("{0}.ZIP", input);

Comment: do you just wish to keep .ZIP for that? extensions?

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(inputString, "\\%.*\\%", replacedWith);`. You can also use just `"%.*%"`.

Comment: See a regex tutorial (with online interactive examples). A character class will match at most one character: that would match “%z%”. An additional QUALIFIER (like * or + is required).

Comment: @Jimi7 It is not necessary to escape the precent characters. That will also match “%%”.

Comment: It sounds [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you trying to achieve? Is it some file name, and you want to rename it? Why not replace everything before `.ZIP`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your expression is that, there is only one alphabet in between `%` signs. You need to repeat the alphabets.

```
Regex.Replace(inputString,"[%][A-Za-z]{1,}[%]", replacedWith);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mahbub ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string input= "%someAlphabets%.ZIP"
string regex = "(%.*%)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "Hello");
```

It doesn't care if the name is alphabet only but that you can change by changing the `.*` caluse to your selection logic.

Comment: @BhushanGoyal welcome :). and please upvote and choose the answer if it was really helpful so the community can use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, you don't need RegEx for this.

More simpler alternatives may be:

1. Using `string.Format`

```cs
string.Format("{0}", input)`
```

2. Using string interpolation

```cs
var input = "Hello";
var result = $"{input}.zip";
```

3. Using `string.Replace` method

```cs
var input = "%pattern%.ZIP"
var with = "Hello"
var result = input.Replace("%pattern%", with);
```